# Google Drive Authorization using token - Server to Server authorization fails to delete another users files (same domain)

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts

I am using the server to server authorization like described in:
[Oauth 2 Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

I have user U1 and U2, both in the same domain.
When I use the API V2 (tried V3 and the same effect) I cannot delete U2s files, and I get 403. We have the same shared directory. 
This does however work when I login via the webpage.
Other requests like file listing or download work.

I acquire the token using

`credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, bytes(private_key, 'UTF-8'), 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', sub=U1@MyDomain.com)`

Does anybody know why does it work on the webpage but not with the API?
Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
The error I am getting is:

`{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "message": "Insufficient permissions for this file",
        "locationType": "other",
        "location": "file.permissions"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient permissions for this file"
  }
}`

When I log in as the user I see the file permissions:
[image]

Where the first user is the owner(U1), the second one(U2) has edit rights, the third one is a general group (to which U1, U2 are assigned and have both edit rights), the last one is just a user who can read.

Comment: Did you give the service account access to the files? What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: More info in the **Edit** section. Thanks for the quick anwser.

Answer (score 0):

You are authenticating as a service account.  Think of a service account as a dummy user.  It has its own google drive account, Google Calendar account and probably a bunch more.   Google drive controls private user data,  U1 owns his files U2 owns his files.  U1 can not access U2's files unless U1 shares the file with U2.  The same goes with service accounts.

```
"message": "Insufficient permissions for this file",
```

Means exactly that. The service account does not have access to the file you are trying to access.  Easiest way to give it access is to take the service account email address and share the file with the service account via the Drive web interfaces like you would any other user.

Note: Domain makes me think you have one of those Google Domain accounts, Google apps or work or something like that. I don't have access to one of those so I cant really test this.  However I read that you can add the service account as a user on the domain and grant it access to all user files.   (Wild guess I will see if I can remember were I read about it.)

Comment: Yes, i Have Google Apps for Work.
I have a service account (Domain Wide Delegation).

I read that:*If you have a Google Apps domain—if you use Google Apps for Work, for example—an administrator of the Google Apps domain can authorize an application to access user data on behalf of users in the Google Apps domain.*
on https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=en_GB#delegatingauthority .

I succesfully impersonate U1 and can upload files on his behalf (U1 as owner). He also has access to U2 files (I can delete them on page). But via API it fails.

Comment: UP. The issue still persists and help in understanding whether it is a design flaw or an error is needed. Like I said I impersonate user X and this user X has the possibility to delete other messages via normal login but not via API. Furthermore the impersonation causes that all files uploaded to the server are owned by user X (so it seems like it is him).